# JavaScript beginner stuck on unexpected error

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript through code academy, and am currently creating a simple rock, paper, scissors game. However, I am stumped by a little error message that says there is an unexpected keyword: else. I have combed through this small block of code dozens of times, but can't seem to find the error, so I figured perhaps a pair of new eyes would be able to find what I am doing wrong.

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
        else if (choice1 === "rock"){
            if (choice2 === "scissors"){
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else { 
                return "paper wins";
            }
    }
        else if (choice1 === "paper");
        {
            if (choice2 === "rock"){
                return "paper wins";
            }
            else {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
    }
        else if (choice1 === "scissors");
        {
            if (choice2 === "rock"){
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else {
                return "scissors wins":
            }
    }


};
```

Comment: Btw there is a typo at `return "scissors wins":` which should end with `;` and not :`. It might actually also be causing your problem or another one once you have solve your current one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition, change the full colon to semi colon in the final return statement.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon at the end there:

```
else if (choice1 === "scissors");
```

And please indent your code normally.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put semicolons after the if expression:

```
if (choice1 === "paper");
```

A semicolon indicates the end of the statement.

Also, a better way to code this would be to use a **switch**

```
switch (choice1) {
    case choice2:
        return "tie";
    case "rock":
        return choice2 === "scissors" ? "rock wins" : "paper wins";
    case "paper":
        return choice2 === "rock" ? "paper wins" : "scissors wins";
    case "scissors":
        return choice2 === "rock" ? "rock wins" : "scissors wins";
}
```

The **switch** statement is a nice way to code when you need to compare a variable against several different values.

The *return choice2 === "rock" ? "rock wins" : "scissors wins";* is a **ternary** statement that evaluates *choice2 === "rock"* and if it is true, it will return *"rock wins"*, otherwise, it will return *"scissors wins"*.